# Does "write an essay" pertain to aviation stack exchange?

Tags: support

I saw the phrase "write an essay" in the answer to a question on meta.stackexchange.com

Does "write an essay" have any specific meaning other than just write a really long answer?  Like, something that falls in a different category from a "question" or an "answer"

If so is it something that is available in aviation stack exchange, or not?

Thank you.

Comment: It may or may not be a good idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like my question wasn't very clear.  It may be clearer now.

Comment: I've searched SE for the "write an essay" comment-- I guess this may have been what I was referring to-- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60449/413377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60449/257476), an "essay" would be one post that discusses both possible answers, including how they relate and differ and why. This is certainly acceptable on the site. Depending on the topic, it doesn't have to be long, but we have some [extremely long answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25327/1696) already. Note that especially with longer answers it's important to include formatting and clear structure to help readers navigate and stay engaged.

Specifically on Aviation.SE, we don't typically see cases where a user posts two answers. In most cases, one answer could discuss the multiple angles. If a user wants to post two completely unrelated and different answers to the same question, it's a sign the question could be too opinion-based to be on topic. People may also see multiple answers by one user as a  cheap attempt to gain reputation, so both answers should be clear in how they are valid answers and show a good amount of effort.

Comment: Thank you.  Glad to see my answers aren't by any means the longest ones ever posted to aviation stack exchange, although they may have set the record for frequency of edits.

Comment: I've searched SE for the "write an essay" comment-- I guess this may have been what I was referring to-- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60449/41337